# Problema con el método IndexOf()

Tags: java, string, eclipse, método, index

El ejercicio me pide lo siguiente:

Escribe un método que se llame obtenerNumeroVecesSubCadena() que recibe dos cadenas y devuelve el
número de veces que la segunda cadena está contenida en el texto de la primera.
Se recomienda utilizar un bucle de búsqueda que utilice la versión adecuada de indexOf() con un contador.

El problema es que siempre me devuelve un 0 y no entiendo por qué.

Aquí dejo el código:

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String texto = "Estamos viviendo en un submarino amarillo";
    String patron = "en";
    
    System.out.println(obtenerNumeroVecesSubCadena(texto, patron));
}
```

**El método:**

```
static int obtenerNumeroVecesSubCadena(String texto, String patron) {
    int contador = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
        if (texto.toUpperCase().indexOf(patron) == 0) {
            contador++;
        }
    }
    
    return contador;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciñéndonos a lo que se pide en el ejercicio, puedes hacerlo de este modo (aquí se usa un bucle `while`):

```
public static int obtenerNumeroVecesSubCadena(String texto, String patron) {
    /*
        Convertimos una sola vez a mayúscula, no cada vez en el bucle
    */
    String textUpper=texto.toUpperCase();
    String patternUpper=patron.toUpperCase();
    int index = 0, count = 0, length = patron.length();
    while( (index = textUpper.indexOf(patternUpper, index)) != -1 ) {                
            index += length; count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Fuente: [Una de las respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588095/5587982) en la pregunta [*Occurrences of substring in a string*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767759/5587982) de Stackoverflow en inglés.

Si te piden un bucle `for` sí o sí, será fácil convertirlo a dicho bucle.

Answer (score 0):

> *El problema es que siempre me devuelve un 0 y no entiendo por qué.*

Notá que lo que devuelve `indexOf()` es la posición en la cadena de texto en la cuál se encuentra la primer ocurrencia de los caracteres que especificas (en tu ejemplo "en").

El condicional que tienes `if (texto.toUpperCase().indexOf(patron) == 0)` lo que valida es si el patrón ocurre al comienzo del texto (posición 0). Por lo que al evaluar esta condición siempre va a ser false (para un texto *"Estamos viviendo en un submarino amarillo*" y un patron "*en*"), porque la ocurrencia del patrón no está al inicio de la cadena y por lo tanto el contador nunca se va a incrementar devolviendote siempre 0.

> *Editado*

`indexOf`en caso de no encontrar el patrón en la cadena te va a devolver `-1` por lo que deberías usar esta información para saber si **al menos 1 vez** encontró el patrón.

Hay un problema al usar un `for` con `indexOf` que de mantener esta idea vas a tener que tener en cuenta: al iterar la misma cantidad de veces que el tamaño del texto podrías tener el problema de que el contador devuelva igual a la longitud del texto, porque cada vez que itera (sobre la cadena completa) encuentra el patrón. Por eso lo ideal sería ir "actualizando" la posición en la que empezás a evaluar tu texto, `indexOf` acepta un segundo parámetro que permite indicar a partir de que posición empezar a evaluar. Este segundo parámetro debería ser variable en tu ejercicio, a mi parecer debería empezar a buscar la ocurrencia del patron desde la posición en la que la última vez encontro el patron +1 (siempre validando los problemas que cada implementacion pueda tener). Es por esto que para este ejercicio por ahí se ajusta mejor un loop `while`, un `for` por ahí serviría mejor si vas a comparar cararter por caracter.

Comment: Muchas gracia!. Pero cuándo pongo el segundo parámetro (le puse un 0), me sigue dando 0

Comment: El problema está en que validas que `indexOf` sea igual a cero, siendo que lo que deberías validar es que sea distinto de "-1" (que es el resultado de cuando no encuentra el texto). Ahora edito la respuesta para agregar esto

Comment: Lo del segundo parámetro lo decía mas que nada por curiosidad y por si querías saltear las ocurrencias previas. Si ponés 0 como segundo parámetro siempre vas a estar checkeando la cadena entera. Lo quito para no sumar confusión

Comment: Ahhhh vale, muchas gracias.